How to use CamelCase instead of SnakeCase in Spring JPA R2DBC
I need to access a legacy database that uses camelCase for both table names and column names.
I had hoped specifying @Table and @Column values with exact matches would work.  But the values I specify are also mapped to snake_case.
There are some references to creating a custom NamingStrategy.  The deepest discussion is on GitHub here.  But the that discussion implies this was fixed in 2021.
I am using the latest spring boot (3.2.5) which includes spring-r2dbc (6.1.6) and the problem is most definitely not fixed.

So very many answers are manipulating Hibernate mapping.  Of course R2DBC does not use hibernate at all.  Still the actual answer turned out to be very close.
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.NamingStrategy;

@EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackages = "xxxx")
public class DataConfig  extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration implements NamingStrategy {

// MUST define your ConnectionFactory here for whatever DB you're using
 public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
...
}

public String getTableName(Class<?> type) {
    // Convert entity class name to table name as per your naming convention
    // For example, replace camelCase with underscores
    return toSnakeCase(type.getSimpleName());
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(RelationalPersistentProperty property) {
    // Convert property name to column name as per your naming convention
    // For example, replace camelCase with underscores
    return toSnakeCase(property.getName());
}

private String toSnakeCase(String camelCase) {
    return camelCase.replaceAll("(.)(\\p{Upper})", "$1$2").toLowerCase();
}

The most important thing is the toSnakeCase.  You can use this to enforce any paradigm you want.  In my case it was as simple as changing the default "$1_$2" to "$1$2".

I´ve stumbled upon it as well. Another solution would be this:
@Bean
    @Primary
    public NamingStrategy testNamingStrategy() {
        return new NamingStrategy() {
            @Override
            public @NonNull String getColumnName(@NonNull RelationalPersistentProperty property) {
                Assert.notNull(property, "Property must not be null.");
                return ParsingUtils.reconcatenateCamelCase(property.getName(), "");
            }

            @Override
            public @NonNull String getTableName(@NonNull Class<?> type) {
                Assert.notNull(type, "Type must not be null.");
                return ParsingUtils.reconcatenateCamelCase(type.getSimpleName(), "");
            }
        };
    }

Use a dedicated NamingStrategy Bean. Maybe you can leave out the Primary Annotation as well - haven´t tested this yet ...
